# Overlay two same sized images in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've got two images that are exactly the same dimensions, all I'm trying to do is take one, make it 50% transparent and place it directly on top of the other, like so:

```
import Image

background = Image.open("bg.png")
overlay = Image.open("over.png")

background = background.convert("RGBA")
overlay = overlay.convert("RGBA")

background_pixels = background.load()
overlay_pixels = overlay.load()

for y in xrange(overlay.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(overlay.size[0]):
         background_pixels[x,y] = (background_pixels[x,y][0], background_pixels[x,y][1], background_pixels[x,y][2], 255)

for y in xrange(overlay.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(overlay.size[0]):
         overlay_pixels[x,y] = (overlay_pixels[x,y][0], overlay_pixels[x,y][1], overlay_pixels[x,y][2], 128)

background.paste(overlay)
background.save("new.png","PNG")
```

But all I get is the 50% transparent overlay (so half way there!).

Comment: The loop over the background to get 0% transparency may not be necessary.

Comment: Use `from PIL import Image` for python 3.x

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try using [blend()](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) instead of paste() - it seems paste() just replaces the original image with what you're pasting in.

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image

background = Image.open("bg.png")
overlay = Image.open("ol.jpg")

background = background.convert("RGBA")
overlay = overlay.convert("RGBA")

new_img = Image.blend(background, overlay, 0.5)
new_img.save("new.png","PNG")
```

Comment: `  File "./overlay.py", line 22, in <module>
    geometry.blend(overlay)
  File "/cfd/software/Python/272/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: blend
`

Comment: I'm on 1.1.7 which is the latest

Answer (score 16):

Maybe too old question, can be done with ease using `opencv`

```
cv2.addWeighted(img1, alpha, img2, beta, gamma)
#setting alpha=1, beta=1, gamma=0 gives direct overlay of two images
```

[Documentation link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Provide the overlay alpha mask parameter and see if this yields results you expected:

```
background.paste(overlay, overlay.size, overlay)
```

Comment: Second param should be (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to resize them to the same shape:

```
b_h, b_w, b_ch = background.shape
W = 800
imgScale = W/b_w
new_b_h,new_b_w = int(b_h*imgScale), int(b_w*imgScale)
new_background = cv2.resize(background,(new_b_w, new_b_h))
```

Then you can fill in the shape fitting both background and foreground.

```
square= np.zeros((new_b_h, new_b_w, b_ch), np.uint8)
square.fill(255)
x= new_b_w
y= new_b_h
offset =0
square[int(y - new_b_h) - offset:int(y)- offset, int(x-new_b_w)- offset:int(x)- offset] = new_background
```

Now you can overlay:

```
OPACITY = 0.7
added_image = cv2.addWeighted(new_background,OPACITY,square, 1-OPACITY, 0)
```

Details are on [github](https://github.com/pydemo/overlay)

Answer (score -1):

The script [here](https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/blend) will also do the task using blend, it also has functionality to resize the images so as to make them the same size if they are not currently.