# Overlay multiple images in python

Tags: python-3.6

My problem is that I have bunch of jpgs and I would like to overlay all of them to see a pattern.

I checked out this answer([Overlay two same sized images in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640114/overlay-two-same-sized-images-in-python)) but it only shows how two images can be overlayed.

Here are the piece of code which shows I'd like to do.

```
for file in os.listdir(SAVE_DIR):
    img1 = cv2.imread(file)
    img2 = cv2.imread('next file name') #provide previous output file here (dst)

    dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)

    cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: how many images you have? can you not follow the steps in the "Overlay two same sized images in Python" again and again? also are your image the same sized?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO yes, I have about 4800 images, I can do 1200 images at one time. They are all the same size.

Comment: Currently, how are you overlay 1200 images? and are these images in file forms? are these files in an array? can you post of what code you are trying currently so I can better help you?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO These images all contain pathways on the same floor map. They are in jpg forms. Currently I am searching the way to do it,

Comment: @OLIVER KOO I've updated code in the post.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to store all your images as a list, and then iterate through each overlapping pair of images and call`cv2.addWeighted()` on each element in your list, passing in the last aggregate image in as `img1` to your subsequent call to cv2.addWeighted().

So for example, say you have 4 images, with names [img1, img2, img3, img4].

You could do

```
jpeg_list = os.listdir(SAVE_DIR)

for i in range(len(jpeg_list)):
    aggregate_file = cv2.imread(jpeg_list[i])
    next_img = cv2.imread(jpeg_list[i+1])
    dst = cv2.addWeighted(aggregate_file, 0.5, next_img, 0.5, 0)
    cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
```